# Sort Documents based on nested child count in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query, kibana-7, elasticsearch-7

My Elasticserch index
Index Name = movies

```
{
   "title": "Chris ENDGAME",
   "cast": [
      {
         "firstName": "Chris",
         "lastName": "Evans"
      },
      {
         "firstName": "Chris",
         "lastName": "Hemsworth"
      },
      {
         "firstName": "Chris",
         "lastName": "Prat"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Similarly,**
I have 3 more movie documents

*Movies2: Winter Soldier*

*cast: Chris Evans, Scarlett Johanson*

*Movies3: Ant-Man*

*cast: Paul Rudd, Michael Pena*

*Movies4: Avengers*

*cast: Chris Evans, Chris Hemsworth*

With this, now I have 4 movies: 1. Endgame; 2.Winter Soldier; 3.Ant-Man; 4.Avengers

**Now,** I want to create an elasticsearch7 search query where if I search *Chris'* (overall: both title and first name) in an order of the number of matches per index searched.

**i.e., OUTPUT(ordered) = Movies1,Movies4,Movies2**, because movie1 has 4 , Movies4 has 2 and Movies2 has 1 chris matching in firstname

**Till now,** I have been able to write a basic query but I have no idea how to order the documents

**My Search Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "multi_match": { "query": "Chris" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do I order it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should provide a nested mapping of your field "cast" as well :

```
PUT test_movies
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "cast": {
        "type": "nested", 
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is the default Elastic Mapping with both keyword and text for each field but the best practice is to specify each field if it's keyword, text or both. Also, in order to change your index mapping, you have to delete and recreate it

Now that your field "cast", is declared as nested, you can do a nested query on it :

```
POST test_movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "cast",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "cast.firstName": "Chris"
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

The `"score_mode": "sum"` will add the score for each sub-match on your nested field

**EDIT**

If you want to search both on the title and the nested child you have to compose with [bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), so your query will be like this :

```
POST test_movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "Chris"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cast",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "cast.firstName": "Chris"
              }
            },
            "score_mode": "sum"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luc E, but the question has changed and rather than searching only the first name I need to check the whole movie (i.e. including the title). I have updated the question.
P.S. my mapping is the same as you described

Comment: i added it, it's the same logic